# PHP LIKE query with oracle database

Tags: php, oracle

```
$ten_desc=$_REQUEST['frm_num'];
$sql = "select * from TENDER_REG where TENDER_DESC LIKE:ten_desc%'";
$stmt=oci_parse($conn,$sql);
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':ten_desc',$ten_desc);
```

displaying error please help

Comment: question unclear, inserted food in the wrong hole. :( ... provide us with more information about your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [Jon Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.

Comment: Your question will be flagged and closed as low quality if you don't change it and give us more information, for example, what are you trying to do, what are the expected results, what is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

The SQL query string will likely confuse PHP and ORACLE. The following will make more sense to both. 1) there is one clear placeholder in the query string. 2) the value passed is complete.

Untested:

replace:

```
$sql = "select * from TENDER_REG where TENDER_DESC LIKE:ten_desc%'";
```

with:

```
$sql = "select * from TENDER_REG where TENDER_DESC LIKE :ten_desc";
```

and:

```
oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':ten_desc',$ten_desc);
```

with:

oci_bind_by_name($stmt,':ten_desc', $ten_desc .'%');